# Hough Transformation OpenCv

Tags: python, performance, opencv, implementation, hough-transform

I implemented own Hough Transformation function in python. It works well.
But own Hough Transformation run slower than OpenCv Hough Transformation function.
I searched source code for OpenCv Hough Transformation and i found this code similar to my code.
After that, I read some article about GPU and CPU implementation.
So this running time difference related to GPU or CPU implementation or something else?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you clarify your question? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Comment: We cannot help you if you don't share your implementation and a pointer to OpenCV implementation.

Comment: I’m pretty sure opencv is implemented in C though? so it is pretty normal it runs faster than your python code, even though they’re both on CPU